# How to make an input field accept alphanumeric data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted (using javascript)the input field below to accept only a combination of letters and numbers or display a message otherwise. It only displays the message if it's empty. Something appears to be wrong and I don't know it exactly.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  function isAlphanumeric(elem, msg){
   var alNumeric = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
   if(elem.value.match(alNumeric)){
   }else{  
     alert(msg)
     elem.focus()
     return false
   }
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input type ='text' id ='letter_number'/>
  <input type ='button' onclick ="isAlphanumeric(document.getElementById('letter_number'), 'Enter a mix of letter and num pls')" value ='letter_number'/>
</form>
```

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wtuwqzv0/ try entering some chars except `0-9`, `a-z`,`A-Z`, you'll see it works expectedly.

Comment: Okay! many thanks. What I actually want is for it to accept only an input containing only alphanumeric data type or display an alert. As it stands, if numeric input enters, no alert. Same goes for only alphabet.

Comment: don't understand what you mean. Try your demo again, entering only numeric chars or alphabetic chars will be passed by the regex and there is not any alert. If possible, you could give ***some example*** of input that the alert should be shown.

Comment: If I understand correctly: You'll need to do 2 checks I think. One to make sure it contains numerical characters and one to make sure it contains alphabet characters.

Comment: @JonathanGray have you tried the demo in my first comment? (which is in fact the OP's code).

Comment: Yes. It does exactly what was asked, but I think the OP wants to make sure there are both numbers and letters or throw the error

Comment: I want alert not displayed when input  (example js1234h, 789jse65 etc) is entered; any other input: purely alphabets or purely numeric should trigger the alert.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is some assertions (only lookahead is supported in Javascript) like this:

```
var alNumeric = /^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z]+$/
```

The assertion `(?=.*?\d)` first checks if there is any `digit` in the string, if it's satisfied, go on to the next assertion `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` which checks for existence of any alphabetic char. If yes, go on to the next expression `[\da-zA-Z]+` that will match only alphanumeric chars.